# Weird rendering on a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, webserver

**Introduction**

I have designed a webiste to display some statistical data. I wanted to add circle charts as a visual representation of the data (for example temperature, speed etc.). My approach was to add a Canvas, then use the canvas' context to draw an arc the appropriate angle of the value. This is shown below and works excelently.

**The Code**

`CircleChart` class:

```
class CircleChart {

    constructor(ID, radius, maxValue, barColor, textSymbol, textColor) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        this.barColor = barColor;
        this.textSymbol = textSymbol;
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.lineWidth = radius/4;
    }

    draw(value) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("stats-canvas" + this.ID);
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.clearRect(0, 0, this.radius*2, this.radius*2);

        context.strokeStyle = this.barColor;
        context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

        let angle = ((2 * Math.PI) / this.maxValue) * value;

        context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, this.radius - (this.lineWidth/2), 0, angle);
        context.stroke();

        //context.fillStyle = this.textColor;
        //context.font = (this.radius/2) + 'px san-serif';
        //context.fillText(value + this.textSymbol, this.x - (this.radius/2) - 15, this.y+10);
    }

}
```

I then have the following definitions:

```
const temp1Circle = new CircleChart(0, 100, 100, 'red', '°C', 'blue');
const temp2Circle = new CircleChart(1, 100, 100, 'red', '°F', 'blue');
const speedCircle = new CircleChart(2, 100, 100, 'red', 'Mph', 'blue');
```

These are the drawn from a function that reads the response from a GET request every 3000 ms. The process is outlined below

1. `setTimeout(attemp_request, 3000);` -> sends a HTTP GET request every 3000 ms, and processes response
2. Split response body into appropriate data (temp, speed etc.)
3. Draw each circle chart, applying the value recieved.

Currently I am generating random data and drawing this as shown below

```
function process_response(http_response_text) {
    // process all data into temp1, temp2 and speed
    update_stats(temp1, temp2, speed);
}

function update_stats(temp1, temp2, speed) {
    temp1Circle.draw(getRandomValue(0, 100));
    temp2Circle.draw(getRandomValue(0, 100));
    speedCircle.draw(getRandomValue(0, 100));
}
```

**The Problem**

When the page is first loaded, the charts draw perfectly. When they are then updated, the following occurs and after a time the page looks like image 2.

Image 1 (first load):
[image: Image 1]

Image 2 (after a few updates):
[image]

Is there something I am missing?
I ensured to call `context.clearRect()' every draw to make sure the canvas is clean before drawing the new arc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a call to [beginPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) before drawing new path (when doing update) so the old path remains (and it's end link to new start, which create the lines).